# How do I change my widget index with a timer?

Tags: python, pyqt, qt4

OK, I trying create a tick so I can show elapsed time and change screens after a time delay.  The pyqt program is as follows:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'mainwindow.ui'
#
# Created: Tue May 10 08:43:50 2016
#      by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.9.3
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import time

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    _fromUtf8 = lambda s: s

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.setEnabled(True)
        MainWindow.resize(800, 480)
        self.centralWidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralWidget"))
        self.stackedWidget = QtGui.QStackedWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.stackedWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 480))
        palette = QtGui.QPalette()
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        self.stackedWidget.setPalette(palette)
        self.stackedWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("stackedWidget"))
        self.page_1 = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.page_1.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("page_1"))
        self.Software_2 = QtGui.QLabel(self.page_1)
        self.Software_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(550, 310, 241, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("DejaVu Sans"))
        font.setPointSize(32)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.Software_2.setFont(font)
        self.Software_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Software_2"))
        self.model_2 = QtGui.QLabel(self.page_1)
        self.model_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 300, 171, 91))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("DejaVu Sans"))
        font.setPointSize(32)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.model_2.setFont(font)
        self.model_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("model_2"))
        self.ModNum_2 = QtGui.QLabel(self.page_1)
        self.ModNum_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 370, 101, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("DejaVu Sans"))
        font.setPointSize(24)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.ModNum_2.setFont(font)
        self.ModNum_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("ModNum_2"))
        self.logo_3 = QtGui.QLabel(self.page_1)
        self.logo_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 60, 571, 191))
        self.logo_3.setText(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.logo_3.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8("../../logo.ppm")))
        self.logo_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("logo_3"))
        self.SoftNum_2 = QtGui.QLabel(self.page_1)
        self.SoftNum_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(570, 370, 171, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("DejaVu Sans"))
        font.setPointSize(24)
        self.SoftNum_2.setFont(font)
        self.SoftNum_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("SoftNum_2"))
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_1)
        self.page_2 = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.page_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("page_2"))
        self.logo_2 = QtGui.QLabel(self.page_2)
        self.logo_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 60, 571, 191))
        self.logo_2.setText(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.logo_2.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8("../../logo.ppm")))
        self.logo_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("logo_2"))
        self.pbElectro = QtGui.QPushButton(self.page_2)
        self.pbElectro.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 360, 171, 32))
        self.pbElectro.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pbElectro"))
        self.pbWater = QtGui.QPushButton(self.page_2)
        self.pbWater.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 360, 131, 32))
        self.pbWater.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pbWater"))
        self.pbMatain = QtGui.QPushButton(self.page_2)
        self.pbMatain.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(572, 360, 181, 32))
        self.pbMatain.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pbMatain"))
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_2)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.Software_2.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Software", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.model_2.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Model", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.ModNum_2.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "3000", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.SoftNum_2.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "V 0.00.01", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pbElectro.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Electrostatic Filtration", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pbWater.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Water Removal", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pbMatain.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Maintenance Mode", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
```

Then my main program is this:

```
import sys
from form import *
import time

from PyQt4.QtCore import QTimer
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication

global myapp
start = time.time()



class MyDialog(QtGui.QMainWindow):
      def __init__(self, parent=None):
          QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
          self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
          self.ui.setupUi(self)
      def Change():
            print('tick')
            Ui_MainWindow.setCurrentIndex(1)

    #self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.Change)

if __name__ == "__main__":
      app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
      myapp = MyDialog()
      myapp.show()
      timer = QTimer()
      timer.timeout.connect(MyDialog.Change)
      timer.start(1000)
      sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The line Ui_MainWindow.setCurrentIndex(1) does not work and gives me an error.
I've tried a lot of things and usually get into trouble with "self".

I could use some help and possibly a little consulting.

Comment: are you trying to make a stopwatch?

Comment: Not really. We ate making an embedded control using a raspberry pi. There are outputs that run for a time period and the screen will show the remaining time. There is also accumulated running hours on motors.

Comment: I come from an embedded control environment usually with a couple of LEDs for indicators or possibly a led display. Normally we establish an interrupt tick for starring a/d readings and updating io. This is counted and Isis for timers. The timers must be running in the background.

Comment: Sorry for the typos.  I was answering from my phone and wasn't correcting.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the function Change, specifically the line `UI_MainWindow.setCurrentIndex(1)`.  `UI_MainWindow` is the name of a class, what you want is an *instance* of the class.  You created such an instance in the `__init__` method of MyDialog; it's `self.ui`.  Therefore the line I referred to above should instead be `self.ui.setCurrentIndex(1)`.  That calls the method `setCurrentIndex` on the instance `self.ui`.

For the record, there are such things as static methods and class methods in Python, so the syntax of your original code is perfectly valid.  You don't get an error until Python tries (and fails) to call a class/static method named `UI_MainWindow.setCurrentIndex`.  Such methods do appear in Qt, for example `QMessageBox.critical`.

Comment: I tried that already.  The error I get is "NameError: global name 'self' is not defined".  Adding self to Change as in def Change(self): gives the error TypeError: Change() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given). I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the fact that the method declaration of `Change` is incorrect.(it should have one argument, `self`).  Also the function call that comes right after the creation of the timer should be `timer.timeout.connect(myapp.Change)`.  Again it's the same confusion between classes and instances; you need an instance of MyDialog here, not the class itself.